# Weird output of tab_model() with glmmTMB

Tags: r, mixed-models, sjplot, glmmtmb

I am getting a weird output when I use the `tab_model()` function of the `sjPlot` package in connection with the `glmmTMB` function of the `glmmTMB` package to fit a generalized linear mixed model with a beta-family response. The intercept and the marginal R² look very weird.

What is going on here?

```r
df <- structure(list(date = structure(c(6L, 5L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("2021-03-17", 
"2021-04-07", "2021-04-13", "2021-04-27", "2021-05-11", "2021-05-27"
), class = "factor"), kettlehole = structure(c(4L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
7L, 2L, 6L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L
), .Label = c("1189", "119", "1202", "149", "172", "2484", "552"
), class = "factor"), plot = structure(c(8L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 
8L, 1L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 7L, 5L, 8L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8"), class = "factor"), treatment = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("a", "b"), class = "factor"), distance = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "5"), class = "factor"), soil_moisture_content = c(0.2173, 
0.1028, 0.148, 0.3852, 0.1535, 0.2618, 0.2295, 0.222, 0.3145, 
0.1482, 0.2442, 0.3225, 0.1715, 0.1598, 0.2358, 0.274, 0.1543, 
0.144, 0.128, 0.361), yield = c(0.518, 0.434, 0.35, 0.599, 0.594, 
0.73, 0.568, 0.442, 0.695, 0.73, 0.667, 0.49, 0.744, 0.56, 0.485, 
0.532, 0.668, 0.511, 0.555, 0.718), weed_coverage = c(0, 0.045, 
0.03, 0.002, 0.11, 0.003, 0.01, 0, 0.02, 0.002, 0, 0.008, 0, 
0.002, 0, 0.006, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.002)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

```r
library(sjPlot)
library(glmmTMB)

glmmTMB(yield ~ soil_moisture_content + weed_coverage + distance + treatment + (1/kettlehole/plot) + (1|date), family = "beta_family", data = df) -> modop

tab_model(modop)
```

[image]

**EDIT**

So here is a screenshot of the result of tab_model() that I used on my actual dataset with n=630. I think the problem is that the model is overfit, as mentioned by Ben and needs to be adjusted by eliminating unncessary predictors.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr** the weird intercept results seem to be a bug in `sjPlot::tab_model`, which should be reported to the maintainers at the [sjPlot issues list](https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues) — it seems that `tab_model` is mistakenly exponentiating the dispersion parameter when it shouldn't.  However, there are other issues with your model (it's probably overfitted) which are what's messing up your marginal R^2 value.

Here is a run of some sensible simulated data that shows the problem with `tab_model()`:

```r
set.seed(101)
## rbeta() function parameterized by mean and shape
my_rbeta <- function(n, mu, shape0) {
  rbeta(n, shape1 = mu*shape0, shape2 = (1-mu)*shape0)
}
n <- 100; ng <- 10
dd <- data.frame(x = rnorm(n),
                 f = factor(rep(1:(n/ng), ng)))
dd <- transform(dd,
                y = my_rbeta(n,
                             mu = plogis(-1 + 2*x + rnorm(ng)[f]),
                             shape0 = 5))

m1 <- glmmTMB(y ~ x + (1|f), family = "beta_family", dd)
tab_model(m1)
```

The results of `sigma(m1)`, `print(m1)`, `summary(m1)` all agree that the estimated dispersion parameter is 5.56 (close to its nominal value of 5), and agree with `confint(m1, "disp_")`:

```r
         2.5 %   97.5 % Estimate
sigma 4.068351 7.606602 5.562942
```

However, `tab_model()` reports:

[image: tab_model output, showing estimated dispersion of 260]

displaying two problems:

- (major) the dispersion is reported as `exp(5.563) = 260.6` instead of 5.563, and confidence intervals are similarly (incorrectly) exponentiated
- (minor) the dispersion parameter is labeled as `(Intercept)`, which is confusing (it is technically the "intercept" of the dispersion model)

However, the R^2 values look sensible — we'll come back to this.

---

What about the model itself?

A reasonable rule of thumb (see e.g. Harrell *Regression Modeling Strategies*) says you should generally aim to have about 1 parameter for every 10-20 observations. Between fixed and random effects, you have 9 parameters (`length(modop$fit$par)`, or `nobs(modop) - df.residual(modop)`) for 20 observations.

If we run `diagnose(modop)` (note I am using a fixed/development version of `diagnose()`, your results may differ slightly) gives:

```r
diagnose(modop)
Unusually large coefficients (|x|>10):

theta_1|date.1 
     -11.77722
```

> Large negative coefficients in zi (log-odds of zero-inflation),
> dispersion, or random effects (log-standard deviations) **suggest
> unnecessary components** (converging to zero on the constrained scale) ...

(if you look at `summary(modop)` you'll see that the estimated standard deviation of the `date` random effect is 7e-6, about 4 orders of magnitude less than the next-largest random effect term ...)

```r
modop2 <- update(modop, . ~ . - (1|date))
```

`diagnose(modop2)` says this model is OK.

However, `tab_model(modop2)` still gives a suspicious conditional R^2 (1.038, i.e. >1). Running `performance::r2_nakagawa(modop2)` directly (I believe this is the underlying machinery used by `tab_model()`) gives:

```r
# R2 for Mixed Models
  Conditional R2: 1.038
     Marginal R2: 0.183
```

but with warnings

> 1: mu of 1.5 is too close to zero, estimate of random effect variances may be unreliable. 
> 2: Model's distribution-specific variance is negative. Results are not reliable.

I would basically conclude that this data set is just a little too small/model is too big to get useful R^2 values.

FWIW I'm slightly concerned that `tab_model()` reports `N_plot = 8` for this model: it ought to be reporting `N_{plot:kettlehole} = 18` as in `summary(modop2)`

Comment: Thanks a lot again for your effort, Ben! The numbers of observations is so small, because I used only a sample of n=20 to create a small repex. My actual data set has n=630. But the problem persists in the actual data set (see edit). On another post of mine regarding a similiar issue, it was said that 
"The default behaviour of most functions in the sjPlot package is to transform values on the log scale using the exp() function, to get something closer to the probability values. If you want the original model values in the log space where the model was fit, you have to specify transform=NULL

Comment: So I understand that I need to eliminate some of the predictors to adjust the model? What is the best way to do this? Can you recommend me a video or something? I have no statistical background and I like when the information is visualized and with as less math as possible. Maybe you know something? :) Cheers!

Comment: What are the results of `diagnose()` applied to your model? Now that the bug in `tab_model()` is resolved, this becomes purely a statistical rather than a programming problem, so I'm going to suggest that you post a revised version on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com). If possible, you should post a link to your data.

Comment: It's not a bug, it's a feature ;)

> diagnose(glmm1)
Unusually large Z-statistics (|x|>5):
soil_moisture 
    -5.086117 

What does it mean? I dont really understand the explanation..

Comment: There's a bug that I fixed just yesterday in `diagnose()`. `remotes::install_github("glmmTMB/glmmTMB/glmmTMB@diagnose_fixes")` if you're eager (you'll need compilers).  I think that message will go away and `diagnose()` will say "model seems OK!".  However, I think if you run `performance::r2_nakagawa()` directly on your model, you'll still see those warnings telling you that the R^2 results are unreliable ...

Comment: PS I shouldn't say the bug is "resolved", but that it's "diagnosed". I did report it: https://github.com/strengejacke/sjPlot/issues/818

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244075/discussion-between-effigy-and-ben-bolker).